# SharpSvn can not get uncommitted files

Tags: c#, svn, sharpsvn

I am using SharpSvn 1.6 on a Win7 64bit machine with SlikSvn v1.7.1. I am using a C# application in VS2010 to check that files are checked in.

I can do a `client.GetInfo()` to get the svn revision of a file from the svn archive but when I do a `client.GetStatus()` to find out if a file in the file system is changed every call returns with "file is not a working copy".

I have noticed that, with SlikSvn 1.7, the .svn files seem to have disappeared from the file system. From what I have read the absence of these files is what is giving me the error.

Any ideas on how to modify either SlikSvn or SharpSvn to overcome this issue?

OK, I have tried to get the status of a folder that DOES have a .svn folder in it and I get the error:

> SharpSvn.SvnWorkingCopyException: The path 'C:\PMech\080-Software'
>   appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater working copy. 
>   Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this working copy.

This is what I have been missing up to now. What exactly do I need to upgrade? The SlikSvn 1.7 is the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

From the Subversion 1.7 release notes:

> Subversion 1.7 clients use a new working copy format. Subversion 1.7 clients cannot use Subversion 1.6 (and earlier) working copies. Existing working copies created with Subversion 1.6 and earlier need to be upgraded before they can be used with a Subversion 1.7 client (see below for details).

If they changed the metadata storage from `.svn` folders to something else, SVN implementations of versions 1.6/earlier and 1.7/later can't possibly interoperate. You'll have to use matching versions of the library / client.

Comment: I'm still confused. Does that mean I need a v1.7 of SharpSvn?

Comment: @sobeyornotsobey Exactly. Either that or you'll have to stick with SlikSvn 1.6 on the command line.